# No architectures to compile for (ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH=YES, active arch=armv7,, VALID_ARCHS=armv7 armv7s)

Tags: armv7

My all simulators and iPhone5s are work.
but my iPadmini said this error when it compiling.

--> No architectures to compile for (ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH=YES, active arch=armv7,, VALID_ARCHS=armv7 armv7s).

My settings are

-architecture = armv7, armv7s

-build active architecture only 
----debug Y
----release N

-valid architecture = armv7, armv7s